# Store error in excel file while performing Selenium test case with Junit

Tags: java, selenium, junit, errorcollector

I want to store errors in excel file while performing Selenium test case over HTML fields with Junit.

My code is:

```
public class ExceptionHandler {

public ErrorCollector errors = new ErrorCollector();


public ErrorCollector getErrors() {
    return errors;
}


public void setErrors(ErrorCollector errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
}


public void execute(ExceptionHandlerTemplate template) {
    System.out.println("Inside execute");
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside try");
        template.execute();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("Inside catch: " + exc);
        errors.addError(exc);
    }
}
```

}

This code is working fine.

But how to retrieve all the errors in variable or datatype. I am using below code:

```
ErrorCollector errCollector = executor.getErrors();
```